# X Error of failed request: BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation), PyOpenGL

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, pyopengl

I have this code:

```
import pygame

from pygame.locals import *
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *


vertices= (
    (1, -1, -1),
    (1, 1, -1),
    (-1, 1, -1),
    (-1, -1, -1),
    (1, -1, 1),
    (1, 1, 1),
    (-1, -1, 1),
    (-1, 1, 1)
    )

edges = ((0,1),(0,3),(0,4),(2,1),(2,3),(2,7),(6,3),(6,4),(6,7),(5,1),(5,4),(5,7))

surfaces = (
(0,1,2,3),
(3,2,7,6),
(6,7,5,4),
(4,5,1,0),
(1,5,7,2),
(4,0,3,6)
)


def Cube():

  glBegin(GL_QUADS)
  for surface in surfaces:
      x = 0
      for vertex in surface:
          x+=1
          glColor3fv(colors[x])
          glVertex3fv(verticies[vertex])
  glEnd()

  glBegin(GL_LINES)
  for edge in edges:
      for vertex in edge:
          glVertex3fv(verticies[vertex])
  glEnd()



def main():

  pygame.init()
  display = (800,600)
  pygame.display.set_mode(display, DOUBLEBUF|OPENGL)

  gluPerspective(45, (display[0]/display[1]), 0.1, 50.0)

  glTranslatef(0.0,0.0, -5)

  while True:

      for event in pygame.event.get():
          if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
              pygame.quit()
              quit()

      glRotatef(1, 3, 1, 1)
      glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
      Cube()
      pygame.display.flip()
      pygame.time.wait(10)



if __name__ == "__main__":

   main()
```

and this error:

> ```
> X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
>   Major opcode of failed request:  154 (GLX)
>   Minor opcode of failed request:  3 (X_GLXCreateContext)
>   Value in failed request:  0x0
>   Serial number of failed request:  25
>   Current serial number in output stream:  26
> ```

I think these three lines have problem, actually line three, display mode:

```
pygame.init()
display = (800,600)
pygame.display.set_mode(display, DOUBLEBUF|OPENGL)
```

Only with this part of code in main function, I have the same problem. If I comment third line in main function I get, of course, error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "cube_0.py", line 66, in 
>       main()
>     File "cube_0.py", line 60, in main
>       pygame.display.flip()
>   pygame.error: Display mode not set

Comment: Please post the *full stack trace*. It has more useful information.

Comment: Please add the `colors` list/tuple to your example and fix the typos (`verticies` should be `vertices`). I've actually already run the code with my own colors list and it works correctly for me.

Comment: Does the code run if you comment out `Cube()` in your while loop? Seems like some driver error more than anything in your code given that there is an error for context creation itself (`X_GLXCreateContext`). It ran fine on my laptop once I made the edits suggested by @skrx by the way. It might help to include what platform, graphics card, and driver is it running on.

Comment: In main function if I comment all lines except first three lines, this is line where I get error: `pygame.display.set_mode(display, DOUBLEBUF|OPENGL) `

Comment: How are you running this code? What drivers do you have installed?
I came across a similar error, when trying to use openGL rendering on a remote machine, and connected to ssh. 
See this for installing the drivers: --no-opengl-files
https://gist.github.com/wangruohui/df039f0dc434d6486f5d4d098aa52d07

Comment: Int the code of your question the list of color attributes is missing (`colors`). The list of vertex coordinates is named  `vertices`, but tried to be accessed by the name `verticies`. After solving this issues, the program runs fine without any error. So this is not a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Correct the question or delete it, because it is useless.

Comment: See [Pygame OpenGL init causes an X Error](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/166421/pygame-opengl-init-causes-an-x-error). The issue has nothing to do with your code. It is causes by your system or graphics driver or possibly you have to update pygame.

Answer (score 2):

On Ubuntu 20.04 (uses bash), `pygame.init()` was giving me the above X Error.
Putting the following in my `~/.bashrc` solved it for me:

```bash
export SDL_VIDEODRIVER='dummy'
```

Note, also that my `$DISPLAY` environment variable is `:0`
One may thus also need the following in `~/.bashrc`.

```bash
export DISPLAY=:0
```

I was also running code from Pycharm, which required me to start `pycharm.sh` from a terminal session that already had the above environment variables initialized (it's a bug in Pycharm 2021).

Answer (score 1):

See [Pygame OpenGL init causes an X Error](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/166421/pygame-opengl-init-causes-an-x-error). The issue has nothing to do with your code. It is causes by your system or graphics driver. Possibly you have to update pygame.